# Wolframscript running slow on linux?

Tags: scripting

I tried running a simple wolframscript example on ubuntu with v11. Why does this example take so long?

```
$time ./city.m london "new york" 5558

 real    5m54.185s 
 user    0m0.134s 
 sys     0m0.005
```

Here's the example script "city.m":

```
#!/usr/local/bin/wolframscript -function -signature City City
Round@QuantityMagnitude[GeoDistance[#1, #2],"Kilometers"]&
```

Comment: Works fine for me on ubuntu M11                                                               "time  city.m  london  newyork  
5558
0.131u 0.008s 0:06.47 2.0% 0+0k 104+208io 0pf+0w,  
{cat city.m   
#!wolframscript -function -signature City City  
Round@QuantityMagnitude[GeoDistance[#1, #2],"Kilometers"]&}"

Comment: @dsingh Weird, thanks for the response